# how to remove /t taxon path in spree 2.x?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, taxonomy

We are developing eCommerce website using Spree, the categories link getting like /t/brand/ruby.

But we have to remove /t on taxon.

Thanks
Thiyagarajan Veluchamy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to do.

1. add following code into routes.rb

   ```
   get '*id', :to => 'spree/taxons#show', :as => :categories
   ```
2. add following code into app/helpers/spree/base_helper_decorator.rb

   ```
   Spree::BaseHelper.module_eval do
     def seo_url(taxon)
       # return spree.nested_taxons_path(taxon.permalink)
       return main_app.categories_path(taxon.permalink)
     end
   end
   ```

Now you can see, without /t

Comment: Can you show me the where in Rails guide/documentation, this style of root declaration has been documented, for namespaced controllers ? I am looking for since yesterday, but no luck!

Comment: Where does 'main_app' come from?

Comment: links to products are broken with this route

Comment: It works, but for taxon page links it still uses /t/ like /t/taxon?page=2. Any ideas on how to correct this ?

Comment: @IuriiBudnikov yep. link is broken. how did u managed to do it? this answer is incomplete